# KnownType Not sufficient for Inclusion

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, compiler-construction, attributes

Why isn't the use of KnownType attribute in C# sufficient for inclusion of a DLL?  Working with Visual Studio 2012 with TFS responsible for builds, I am on a project in which a service required use of this attribute as in the following:

```
using Project.That.Contains.RequiredClassName;

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, Namespace="SomeNamespace")]
[KnownType(typeof(RequiredClassName))]
public class Service : IService { }
```

But to get the required DLL to be included in the bin output and therefore the installer from our production build, I had to add the follow to the constructor for Service:

```
public Service() { 
    // Exists only to force inclusion
    var ignore = new RequiredClassName();
}
```

So, given that the project that contains RequiredClassName is itself referenced by the project that contains Service, why isn't the use of the KnownType attribute sufficient for inclusion of DLL in the output?

Comment: Ask yourself: why would the DLL have to be included in a project, if nothing within that DLL is being called or instantiated?

Comment: It is being called.  The problem is that it is not being called directly.  When the call is made to a routine within the service over WCF, the object passed must be deserialized.  It is that deserialization process that fails. The RequiredClassName is referenced within the the object that must be deserialized but otherwise not used directly within the service itself.

Comment: In case someone else runs into this issue in the future, I have found the solution.  The fundamental issue was in the DLL versions. And old version of an assembly was used in compilation.  This created an expectation that the service, deployed with the updated version, could not match.  The central confusion lay in the deployment in which we install assemblies into the GAC.  Not knowing this fact, I assumed that it was not including the DLL when building the installer.